# jquery textarea inside html tag strip/remove

Tags: jquery, html, tags, textarea

I want to count characters in textarea but i dont want it to count html tags.

Snippet :

```js
$('#m-summary').keyup(function() {
  var sumTxt=$('#m-summary').val().length;
  if(sumTxt < 200) {
    $('#result-summary').html("<span>200 / </span><span style='font- style:normal;font-weight:bold;'>"+sumTxt+"</span>");
  }
  else {
    $('#result-summary').html("<span style='color:green'>200 / </span><span style='color:green;font-style:normal;font-  weight:bold;'>"+sumTxt+"</span>");
  }
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-area">
  <textarea name="m_summary" id="m-summary"></textarea>
  <div id="result-summary">200 / 0</div>
</div>
```

I write inside textarea : **hello** . count length = 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use : `str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")`

Snippet:

```js
$('#m-summary').keyup(function() {
  var sT=$('#m-summary').val().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
  var sumTxt=sT.length;
  if(sumTxt < 200) {
    $('#result-summary').html("<span>200 / </span><span style='font- style:normal;font-weight:bold;'>"+sumTxt+"</span>");
  }
  else {
    $('#result-summary').html("<span style='color:green'>200 / </span><span style='color:green;font-style:normal;font-  weight:bold;'>"+sumTxt+"</span>");
  }
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-area">
  <textarea name="m_summary" id="m-summary"></textarea>
  <div id="result-summary">200 / 0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html is contained in a string, then you will need an html parser to strip out the html and then count the string, something like http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/. This is if I understood the question correctly if not and you simply want the length of the string inside the text area try:

```
$("#m-summary").text().length;
```

I also would prefer you try native javascript for this:

```
document.getElementById("m-summary").value.length
```

Answer (score -2):

`$("#m-summary").text()` will give you just the text not html tags then you can check the length like this:

```
var textval = $("#m-summary").text();
console.log(textval.length());
```